# close a square root function

Tags: sqrt

I want to make an addition of two square root functions, not one inside another.
here is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
    L=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\left\|y_{pred} -y_{true}\right\|_{2}}  +
    \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\left\|y_{pred1} -y_{pred2}\right\|_{2}}
\end{equation}
```

And the output is:[image]
Can anyone tell me what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Unrelated, might be am idea to use `y_{\mathrm{pred}}`. Additionally all the `\left...\right` in this example does nothing.

Comment: Off-topic: Should it be `^2` instead of `_2` in all instances of `\right\|_{2}`?

Comment: @Mico it might be a 2 norm, like the `\lVert_p` norm?

Comment: Another unrelated, generally `\|` is a bad symbol to use for norm, use `\lVert ... \rVert` instead. Why? Try `\| -1 \|` and `\lVert -1 \rVert`.

Comment: Please, read terminal or log output. Three must be TeX error messages. If there is an error then the PDF output is irrelevant. Don't waste time with astonishment at PDF output if there is an error message.

Comment: @daleif - Given that `L` is defined as the square root of the average of a bunch of terms, these terms better be the squared norms rather than just the norms themselves. Actually, there's another fairly serious deficiency in the OP's notation: the summation is taken over a bunch of terms indexed by `i`, yet none of terms being summed has an `i` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put too much `\left` delimiters.
[image: sum of sqrts]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \begin{equation}
        L=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\|y_{pred} -y_{true}\right\|_{2}}  + \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\|y_{pred1} -y_{pred2}\right\|_{2}}    
   \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice bro! Because I just know how to use norm yesterday, and I am confused with that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Obviously, I didn't correct the mathematical visible *errors*, but you may follow the comments on your OP.